# Selenium - Wait until page is fully loaded

Tags: python, selenium

Using Python w Selenium to retrieve a web page generated by Splunk. The web page contains a table/list which takes a long time to load.

Upon loading the web page, Splunk provides the web page, except for that table/list. The area where the table should be present, Splunk returns the string 'Waiting for data', as Splunk performs the search query in the background to finish, to the table/list.

The issue I'm facing is that sometimes Selenium returns a proper table/list, and sometimes content with the string 'Waiting for data'.

I thought using the `driver.implicitly_wait()` would fix this issue, but it didn't.

**Q:** How can I configure Selenium to wait w proceeding until the string 'Waiting for data' is not present on the web-page. Or how can I configure Selenium until the page is 'fully' loaded.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML of the table including the loader element.

Comment: It's Splunk. So even when the page is fully loaded, when I right on the web page, and click "show source", the source doesn't display the table at all and/or other objects...

Comment: Splunk or anything whatsoever, if the application renders within any browser, Selenium would be able to identify the elements.

Comment: So, is this even possible w Selenium? I guess the wrong tool here is used.

Comment: Well in short `driver.implicitly_wait()` won't take us anywhere. The only answer gives you the right direction. However I feel you need a bit deeper guidance on how to handle the desired elements. We can discuss at lenght in the [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room sometime later.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with use of [Expected Conditions](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) explicit waits.
`WebdriverWait` Expected Conditions are making `Selenium` `Webdriver` to wait for some condition like presence, visibility, invisibility etc. of web elements.
here you want to wait for invisibility of some specific web element.
With the following imports

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

you can create an instance object of `WebDriverWait` with

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
```

The code waiting for invisibility of the desired element can be like the following:

```py
wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(),'Waiting for data')]")))
```

`driver.implicitly_wait()` may be used to define the `driver` timeout for waiting for presence of elements when using `driver.find_element` or `driver.find_elements` commands only.